# Remove everything except for the URL's in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

After manually scraping Google search results with a legal Chrome plugin, I have the following information (for just two search results):

```
The History Teacher (@THTjournal) | Twitter
https://twitter.com/thtjournal  https://twitter.com/thtjournal
Vertaal deze pagina https://translate.google.nl/translate?hl=nl&sl=en&u=https://twitter.com/thtjournal&prev=search
Jim Carroll (@jcarrollhistory) | Twitter
https://twitter.com/jcarrollhistory https://twitter.com/jcarrollhistory
Vertaal deze pagina https://translate.google.nl/translate?hl=nl&sl=en&u=https://twitter.com/jcarrollhistory&prev=search
```

My goal is to create a list with Twitter URL's like this:

```
https://twitter.com/thtjournal

https://twitter.com/jcarrollhistory
```

I have Notepad++ so how can I use it to get a list with only the URL's? Everything else should be deleted.

Comment: Maybe look up a regex to get and match only the first `https://twitter` string plug anything after it until you get any sort of space then move on to the next like and search and match it. After that, you probably want to find a way to remove duplicates if some lines may be the same if that is a concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(\bhttps://twitter\.com/\w+)?.*$`
- Replace with: `(?1$1:)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                           # beginning of line
  .*?                       # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  (                         # start grpup 1
    \b                      # word boundary
    https://twitter\.com/   # literally
    \w+                     # 1 or more word character
  )?                        # end group, optional
  .*                        # 0 or more any character but newline
$                           # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1$1:)         # if group 1 exists, then use it as replacement, else replace with nothing
```

**Result for given example:**

```
https://twitter.com/thtjournal


https://twitter.com/jcarrollhistory
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have a regex expression that defines a URL, and let's call it *regex*.

Use in Notepad++ the Find dialog, Replace tab, to do *Replace All* of *regex* by `\n$1\n`.
This will separate all the URLs into lines which only contain the URL, interspersed with garbage lines.

Again in the Find dialog, Mark tab, mark all lines containing *regex* using
the *Bookmark line* option, using the *Mark All* operation.

Last, in the *Search => Bookmark* menu, select the option of *Remove Unbookmarked Lines*.

For a good regex expression for URLs, see this post :
[What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).

For more information and screenshots see this article for a similar case :
[Notepad++ how to extract email addresses from a file](https://www.ybierling.com/en/blog-various-nppextractemailfromfile).